# Xcrud with codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, crud

I'm a very happy user of XCRUD V 1.6. I want to integrate it in Codeigniter 3 but when I use the codeigniter session-library in for my XCRUD-pages I get an error in XCRUD: "The verification key is out of date". When the session-library from codeigniter is not being used, XCRUD is working fine. Is there anyone who can tell me how to fix? I need the codeigniter session-library in my xcrud pages for user-details.

This is my current controller: (the session library is loaded in the login_model)

```
    <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Cms extends CI_Controller {



    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        include('cms/xcrud/xcrud.php');
        $this->load->model("login_model");

    }


    public function nieuws()
    {

    $xcrud = Xcrud::get_instance();
        $xcrud->table('nieuws');
        $output['output'] = $xcrud->render();
        $this->_cms_output($output); 
    }



    function useAuthorID($post_array) {
    $post_array['afdeling_id'] = $this->login_model->id();
    return $post_array;
}   
function useCatID($post_array) {
    $post_array['nieuwscat_afdeling_id'] = $this->login_model->id();
    return $post_array;
}   


    function _cms_output($output = null)

    {

        $this->load->view('beheer/default',$output);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using xcrud's CI integration examples, you may try the following in xcrud_config.php:

1. Use the same session name that your CI installation is using, if it differs from "PHPSESSID".
2. Use alternative session.